# sp_executesql - Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working with Entity Framework in C# and am having an issue which I have tracked down to the SQL statement being generated.

The stored procedure takes in a table-valued parameter, but this doesn't seem to be the issue.

In SQL Profiler, I am seeing the following being executed:

```
declare @p3 dbo.PositiveTypes
insert into @p3 values(N'1')
insert into @p3 values(N'4')
insert into @p3 values(N'6')

    exec sp_executesql N'dbo.SaveResults',
                       N'@resultID int, @positiveResults [PositiveTypes] READONLY',
                         @resultID=1,
                         @positiveResults=@p3
```

This results in:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure SaveResults, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'SaveResults' expects parameter '@resultID', which was not supplied.

The definition of this procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveResults] 
    @resultID int, 
    @positiveResults AS dbo.PositiveTypes READONLY
```

User defined type is:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PositiveTypes] AS TABLE(
    [TypeID] [tinyint] NULL
)
```

What is wrong with this `sp_executesql` syntax?  Why does it think that `@resultID` is not being passed properly here?

Comment: How are you executing this? Is there no way of setting the command type so EF knows it is a stored procedure?

Comment: It's being executed in EF using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand on the DbContext.  It seems to recognize it as a stored procedure based on the error message from SQL Server ("procedure or function" ... expects "parameter"). I am trying to determine exactly what is wrong with the sp_executesql syntax and then work backwards to rework the code as needed.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought there might be some command type equivalent [but doesn't appear to be the case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database_methods(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `sp_executesql` to run the SQL text `dbo.SaveResults`. This T-SQL runs the procedure `dbo.SaveResults` with no parameters. Now you understand where that message comes from. What to do about it? Use `EXEC`:

```
EXEC dbo.SaveResults @resultID = 1234, @positiveResults = @p3
```

Or, nest the call:

```
exec sp_executesql N'

    EXEC dbo.SaveResults @resultID = @resultID, @positiveResults = @positiveResults

',N'@resultID int, @positiveResults [PositiveTypes] READONLY',@resultID=1,@positiveResults=@p3
```

I have indented to make it more clear. The 2nd variant is not useful as far as I can tell. Use the first one.

Comment: Unfortunatly the framework I am using is generating the statement using sp_executesql.  I do have control to execute this manually but would prefer to let it continue to generate the statement.  I have attempted to include the EXEC into the generated string but I am getting the same result .. ie exec sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.SaveResults ...'

Comment: Post an executable repro (what you capture with SQL Profiler). It is unclear to me what the problem is now.

Comment: The repro is exactly as described in the original post (first SQL code block).  That is what is coming through SQL Profiler.  Changing N'dbo.SaveResults' to N'EXEC dbo.SaveResults' there results in the same "expects parameter @resultID" error message.

Comment: Yes, that results in the same message because you are not passing parameters. Note, that my second code block does pass parameters in the EXEC line. Add those.

Comment: I was passing them, they were off to the right in the scroll area.  I have reformatted the original question to show the full query without scrolling.  It seems to match your suggestion.

Comment: Not sure where the misunderstanding is. Tell me: What parameters are passed in the following T-SQL batch? `dbo.SaveResults`. This is not a trick question. I'm trying to find out where exactly we disagree.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same exact issue.

Once you declare the command, you have to specify the command type

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"sp_name", con);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

If you don't do this, .NET will generate a command for using `sp_executesql...` and that is the problem is `...` you specify the command type as above and the code generated is using

```
execute storedprocedure @param1 = ...
```

Comment: This is correct.!  CommandType is the magic and causes SqlCommand to generate the correct db statement and all you need to pass is the Name of the sp.    I refactored and broke some code because I left out the CommandType. After stumbling to this article I had an Ah ha!! idiot.  undo-undo. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify the parameter mappings in your sql string for it to work. i.e in the C# code replace

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("EXEC dbo.SaveResults", resultId, positiveResults)
```

with

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("EXEC dbo.SaveResults @resultId=@resultId, @positiveResults=@positiveResults", resultId, positiveResults)
```

It seems `sp_executesql` is unable to automatically associate the passed parameters to the expected parameters when executing a stored procedure unless the mappings are manually specified in the SQL string passed