# sp_executesql reports missing parameter, but parameter is supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I wrote a stored procedure that behaves as expected in SSMS, but reports a syntax error when executed using ADO.NET from a C# application.

I can, in SSMS, execute:

```
exec ige.GetSetComponentSlotValue 
     @setId = 1, @area = 2, @segmentSequence = 3, @slot = 4, @component = 5;
```

It behaves as expected.

The C# code generates and tries:

```
exec sys.sp_executesql N'ige.GetSetComponentSlotValue'
             , N'@setId int,@area int,@segmentSequence int,@slot int,@component int'
             , @setId = 1
             , @area = 2
             , @segmentSequence = 3
             , @slot = 4
             , @component = 5;
```

and reports a syntax error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure ige.GetSetComponentSlotValue, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Procedure or function 'GetSetComponentSlotValue' expects parameter '@setId', which was not supplied.

I copied this from SQL Server Profiler, watching the target database.  When I paste it into SSMS and execute, I see the same error. I don't see the syntax error. Can any of you see it?

Comment: Share your C# code, we can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: I thought the C# code would be a distraction, since I can recreate the issue totally in the context of SSMS.

Comment: The issue, in SSMS, is that you *aren't* passing any parameters to the procedure`ige.GetSetComponentSlotValue`, as the error states, they're only being passed to `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: Yes, when I saw the error, I should have thought, "Why doesn't the server recognize this as a SP?" and that would have saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, got it.
I read
[sp_executesql - Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003520/sp-executesql-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied?rq=2)

I had forgotten to set the CommandType to stored procedure.  The string the C# code should generate is just:

```
exec ige.GetSetComponentSlotValue @setId=1,@area=2,@segmentSequence=3,@slot=4,@component=5;
```